# auto-loading the doctrine 2 with codeigniter 2.1.0

Tags: codeigniter, doctrine-orm

i've a problem in auto-loading the doctrine 2 with codeigniter 2.1.0, 
i was following this tutorial 
http://www.phpandstuff.com/articles/codeigniter-doctrine-from-scratch-day-1-install-and-setup
i was supposed to open the autoload.php file and load the doctrine like this :

```
$autoload['plugin'] = array('doctrine');
```

but the problem is that there is no $autoload['plugin'] = array(); in my autoload.php

so how to load the doctrine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That phpandstuff article is too old and for doctrine1. Use this for CI2 and Doctrine2 
https://github.com/rubensarrio/codeigniter-hmvc-doctrine

you need to setup a library class and setup doctrine classloader.

Comment: I use it for almost all my projects, and is the best integration of CI2 and Doctrine. Please mark as accepted if it helped you ;)

Comment: Hi, I would like to know if using codeigniter $this->doctrine will give me a singleton instance of database connection ? Or this depends on how i make my Doctrine class ?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm right since the version 2.0 of `CodeIgniter` the plugin has been removed and has been added the helper class which is almost the same thing.
I thin you should transform your `plugin` in a `helper`:

`yourplugin_pi.php` => `yournewhelper_helper.php`

and then you can add it in the autoload file in the helper section:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_200.html